# Using IndexDB across users on Chromebooks

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, chromebook

I'm using indexDB now to cache level data for a game.  I do not have access to a Chromebook - but would like to know if the data is shared like it is on browsers.  What I'm concerned about is that each user of the Chromebook would have their own version of the DB, is that the case?

I open it normally with something like:

```
var store = window.indexedDB.open("LevelContent", 3);
```

and store the data with the level key (no user information is stored.)

I've read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) and [this on HTML5Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/), but no mention of multiple users on machines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each user profile on the device has separate storage, for both web APIs and downloaded files.